# "Almost everywhere" bound for the function $f(x)=\frac{\sin(9\pi x)\sin(100\pi x)}{\sin(\pi x)\sin(90\pi x)}.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry, upper-lower-bounds

Consider the function $f\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$f(x)=\frac{\sin(9\pi x)\sin(100\pi x)}{\sin(\pi x)\sin(90\pi x)}.$$
I want to bound this function for certain values of $x$ but I don't know how to make a more precise statement. I'm also only interested in $|f(a/10^m)|$ where $m$ is a fixed positive integers and $a$ is an integer such that $0\lt a \lt 10^m$.

What I think is true is that $|f(a/10^m)|\le 10$ for almost all values $a$. More precisely, $|f(x)|$ is big only when $\sin(90\pi x)=0$, therefore $|f(a/10^m)|$ is big when $90\pi a/10^m$ is a multiple of $\pi$, i.e., the problem will be when $a\approx n\cdot \frac{10^{m-1}}{9}$ ($n=1,\ldots, 90$) so for instance if $m=3$, $|f(a/10^3)|$ is big only when $a$ is close to multiples of $11$. Now my question is how close does $a$ has to be to $n\cdot \frac{10^{m-1}}{9}$  in order for $|f(a/10^m)|$ to be greater than $10$.

Is it possible to make an statement as follows? For every $n=1,\ldots, 90$ there exists some $\varepsilon_n$ such that if $|a-n\cdot \frac{10^{m-1}}{9}|\gt \varepsilon_n$, then $|f(a/10^m)|\le 10$. And if so, how can I prove this?

Comment: I think you need to consider the negative domain of f(x) as well. So I think whenever you write "f<=10", it should have absolute value bars, i.e. |f|<=10.

Comment: yes, you are right, I just edited the question

Comment: The answer of the question whether or not it's possible to make a statement is: Yes! In fact, you've already made the statement (though I'd switch the direction of the inequallities, since |x-lim| < epsilon is the standard epsilon-delta expression). The difficulty of answering the 2nd question comes from the nature of f(x) - it's very hard to deal with, since the argumetns of the sines have such large coefficients.